# Yodlee executeUserSearchRequest error

Tags: yodlee

I try to get information from Yodlee API.
I have a test user where I've implemented adding an account and I got refresh OK from the site:

```
{ siteRefreshStatus: {
      siteRefreshStatusId: 8
      siteRefreshStatus: "REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT"
  }
  - siteRefreshMode: {
      refreshModeId: 2
      refreshMode: "NORMAL"
  }
  - updateInitTime: 0
     nextUpdate: 1391603301
     code: 403
     noOfRetry: 0
  }
}
```

Now when I try to perform search and get the actual transactions I get this error:

```
{
   errorOccured: "true"
   exceptionType: "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException"
   refrenceCode: "_57c250a9-71e8-4d4b-830d-0f51a4811516"
   message: "Invalid argument value: Container type cannot be null"
}
```

The problem is that I have container type!

Check out the parameters I send:

> cobSessionToken=08062013_2%3Ad02590d4474591e507129bf6baaa58e81cd9eaacb5753e9441cd0b1ca3b8bd00a3e6b6a943956e947458307c1bb94b505e2eb4398f890040a3db8c98606c0392&userSessionToken=08062013_0%3A8e8ef9dd4f294e0f16dedf98c1794b96bf33f2e1f2686eda2f35dfe4901dd3a871eed6d08ce52c99a74deb004c025ebf4bf94c7b17baf8ba18aacb331588f5f5&transactionSearchRequest.containerType=bank&transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit=1000&transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit=1&transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=500&transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1&transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId=1&transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName=DataSearchService&transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=true&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode=USD&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate=01-01-2014&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate=01-31-2014&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter+.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId+.identifier=10008425&transactionSearchRequest.searchClients=DEFAULT_SERVICE_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

There is an error occurred while adding the account, which can be interpreted by this parameter `code: 403` and hence you will not be seeing that account when you call the getItemSummary API. An account is successfully linked if the code has zero as value. E.g.`code:0` . 403 is an error which is show if Yodlee's data agent has encountered an unhandled use case. Hence for any such error you should file a service request using Yodlee customer care tool.

To know more about error codes please visit - 
https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes

The status is show as completed`siteRefreshStatus: "REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT"`because addition of any account is followed by a refresh in which Yodlee's data agent logs into the websites of FIs and try scraping data. Hence completion of this activity is denoted as REFRESH_COMPLETED even when there is an error occurred.

> TranasctionSearch issue -

I can see two of the parameters with a "+" sign. Since transactionSlipttype and containerType are dependent on each other the error is thrown.

```
&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter+.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
&transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId+.identifier=10008425
```

The right parameters are  -

```
 &transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
 &transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier=10008425
```